need explanation about proofing limit Superior and inferior
Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ defined $s_n = sup\{x_k | k \ge n\}$ and $t_n = inf\{x_k | k \ge n\}$. Prove that $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are convergent.Then prove if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(t_n)$ then $(x_n)$ converges.
proof
We are given that the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded, so there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$
  |x_n| \leq M \quad \text{for every } n.
  $$
Next, we define
$
s_n = \sup \{ x_k \mid k \geq n \} \quad \text{and} \quad t_n = \inf \{ x_k \mid k \geq n \}.
$
Since $(x_n)$ is bounded by $M$, it follows that both $s_n$ and $t_n$ are also bounded by $M$. Thus, both sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are bounded.
Let $E_n = \{ x_k \mid k \geq n \}$. Since $E_{n+1} \subseteq E_n$, we have $\sup E_n \geq \sup E_{n+1} \quad \text{and} \quad \inf E_n \leq \inf E_{n+1}.$ In other words, $(s_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence, and $(t_n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence.
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, since both $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are bounded and monotonic, they must converge. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = L.$
From the definitions of $s_n$ and $t_n$, we know that $t_n \leq x_n \leq s_n \quad \text{for all } n,$ which gives:$ t_n \leq x_n \leq s_n.$
By the Squeeze Theorem, it follows that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L.$
Thus, the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, which is the limit inferior and limit superior of $(x_n)$.
does the proof of $\sup E_n \geq \sup E_{n+1} \quad \text{and} \quad \inf E_n \leq \inf E_{n+1}.$ need to be explained again? if yes how to write it?
is the squeeze theorem appropriate to implement in this case?
